# Select 2 rows and switch the values

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, sql-update, where-clause

I've a table in SQL named "TAB_Movimentos" which have "Lançamento", "Banco" and "Ordem" and other stuff...

I load it in my "Histórico" datagrid and I hide "Ordem" (Order) column (because it's only for internal use)

I want to switch row order when a specify event occurs, to do that, I've to change "Ordem" from the 2 selected rows.

The problem is that I hide this "Ordem" column, so I can only get it by consulting my SQL table. Because of that, I've to make 2 request to get data, store them and make 2 request do update them. I think there's a **simpler/faster** way to do that.

> **That's what I need, that works! Using a lot of Sqlcommand but I want to use 1 command instead.**

```
A = "SELECT Ordem FROM TAB_Movimentos WHERE Lançamento = '1' AND Banco = '1'" 
B = "SELECT Ordem FROM TAB_Movimentos WHERE Lançamento = '2' AND Banco = '2'" 

"UPDATE TAB_Movimentos SET Ordem = 'A' WHERE Lançamento = '2' AND Banco = '2'"
"UPDATE TAB_Movimentos SET Ordem = 'B' WHERE Lançamento = '1' AND Banco = '1'"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn't there a DataTable associated to the DataGridView? Use that.

Comment: The column data is still in the .DataSource (the DataTable) of the DataGridView when you simply change the .Visible property of the column. There is no need to hit the database again to get the Ordem column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select`s can be merged using boolean logic:

```
SELECT Ordem 
FROM TAB_Movimentos 
WHERE (Lançamento = 1 AND Banco = 1) OR (Lançamento = 2 AND Banco = 2)
```

Some databases support tuple equality, like:

```
WHERE (Lançamento, Banco ) IN ( (1, 1), (2, 2) )
```

As for the `update`s, you can use conditional logic:

```
UPDATE TAB_Movimentos 
SET Ordem = CASE 
    WHEN Lançamento = 2 AND Banco = 2 THEN 'A' 
    WHEN Lançamento = 1 AND Banco = 1 THEN 'B'
END
WHERE (Lançamento = 1 AND Banco = 1) OR (Lançamento = 2 AND Banco = 2)
```

If you are running ms-access, you need `IIF()` instead of `CASE`.

Note that these queries treats `Lançamento` and `Banco` as numbers, because they look like numbers. If they really are sting, you can add back the single quotes around `1` and `2`.